# How to avoid stackable lineItems in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

So I have a product which gets personalized on the product detail page. Since it has been personalized it doesn't make sense to stack it in the cart anymore, because the individual personalized information is shown on the lineItem. Therefor it needs to create a new lineItem for each personalized product.

Now, there is the stackable flag on lineItems. If set to `false` the cart crashes with a `CartException`.

Also I found the solution of creating a new `UUID` for each personalized lineItem on the `BeforeLineItemAddedEvent` like this:

```php
$event->getLineItem()->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
```

This seems to solve the issue at first glance. However, now another issue occurs. With the changed lineItem Id the available stock calculation doesn't work properly anymore. So one can add as many personalized products to the cart, even though the available stock doesn't allow it. Just the message "The product "X" is only available Y times" and the checkout is disabled.

I think my approach on doing this is not correct.

How can solve this issue?

Comment: To avoid stacking (which also let's you no longer change the quantity), you could use `$event->getLineItem()->setStackable(false);` - but that's probably not what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I already tried that. It leads to a `CartException` once you add that product to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement for my shop. Shopware stacks the products in the cart by its id. You have to create your own CartLineItemController to change this behavior.

I save the product customization in the payload and use this to create a unique id for this line-item. If a customer want to order more than one product with the same customization, it stacks in the cart. If not then not.

It is this part:

```
if ($payload['config']) {
    $keyId = md5($lineItemData->getAlnum('id') . serialize($payload['config']));
} else {
    $keyId = $lineItemData->getAlnum('id');
}
```

From this file:

```
class CartLineItemController extends StorefrontController
{
    private CartService $cartService;

    private PromotionItemBuilder $promotionItemBuilder;

    private ProductLineItemFactory $productLineItemFactory;

    private HtmlSanitizer $htmlSanitizer;

    private AbstractProductListRoute $productListRoute;

    /**
     * @internal
     */
    public function __construct(
        CartService $cartService,
        PromotionItemBuilder $promotionItemBuilder,
        ProductLineItemFactory $productLineItemFactory,
        HtmlSanitizer $htmlSanitizer,
        AbstractProductListRoute $productListRoute
    ) {
        $this->cartService = $cartService;
        $this->promotionItemBuilder = $promotionItemBuilder;
        $this->productLineItemFactory = $productLineItemFactory;
        $this->htmlSanitizer = $htmlSanitizer;
        $this->productListRoute = $productListRoute;
    }

    public function addLineItems(Cart $cart, RequestDataBag $requestDataBag, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        return Profiler::trace('cart::add-line-item', function () use ($cart, $requestDataBag, $request, $context) {
            /** @var RequestDataBag|null $lineItems */
            $lineItems = $requestDataBag->get('lineItems');
            if (!$lineItems) {
                throw new MissingRequestParameterException('lineItems');
            }

            $count = 0;

            try {
                $items = [];

                /** @var RequestDataBag $lineItemData */
                foreach ($lineItems as $lineItemData) {

                    $payload = null;
                    if ($lineItemData->get('payload')) {

                        $payload = $lineItemData->get('payload')->all();

                        if ($payload['config']) {
                            $keyId = md5($lineItemData->getAlnum('id') . serialize($payload['config']));
                        } else {
                            $keyId = $lineItemData->getAlnum('id');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $keyId = $lineItemData->getAlnum('id');
                    }

                    $lineItem = new LineItem(
                        $keyId,
                        $lineItemData->getAlnum('type'),
                        $lineItemData->get('referencedId'),
                        $lineItemData->getInt('quantity', 1)
                    );

                    $lineItem->setStackable($lineItemData->getBoolean('stackable', true));
                    $lineItem->setRemovable($lineItemData->getBoolean('removable', true));

                    if ($payload) {
                        $lineItem->setPayload($payload);
                    }


                    $count += $lineItem->getQuantity();

                    $items[] = $lineItem;
                }

                $cart = $this->cartService->add($cart, $items, $context);

                if (!$this->traceErrors($cart)) {
                    $this->addFlash(self::SUCCESS, $this->trans('checkout.addToCartSuccess', ['%count%' => $count]));
                }
            } catch (ProductNotFoundException $exception) {
                $this->addFlash(self::DANGER, $this->trans('error.addToCartError'));
            }

            return $this->createActionResponse($request);
        });
    }

    private function traceErrors(Cart $cart): bool
    {
        if ($cart->getErrors()->count() <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->addCartErrors($cart, function (Error $error) {
            return $error->isPersistent();
        });

        return true;
    }

}
```